# Retrieve values with document.execCommand

Tags: javascript

See `document.execCommand` commands docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801229(v=vs.85).aspx#fontsize

They say that `document.execCommand` can be used to retrieve values:

> Sets or retrieves the font size for the current selection.

I can set the font-size for example, but I can't get the current value... The docs don't provide any examples (only for setting values).

Tried ommiting the value parameter, and also the UI parameter but I'm unable to get anything.